# Incorrect syntax near default in alter table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to alter the existing column `Site_SiteId` in SQL Server to make it as not null with default value 1 but getting a syntax error:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ImagingEvents 
    ALTER COLUMN Site_SiteId bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
```

Comment: Does a default value already exist?

Comment: Did you consider reviewing the [syntax for alter table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax-for-disk-based-tables)? You cannot alter a column and add a default constraint at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

`default` is a constraint so you need to ***add it to the table***:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ImagingEvents ADD DEFAULT 1 FOR Site_SiteId
```

Comment: Can't you show OP all steps to get "ALTER COLUMN Site_SiteId bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 1"?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to `ALTER` the column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.ImagingEvents ALTER COLUMN Site_SiteId bit NOT NULL;
```

Note that if you have any rows that already have the value `NULL` you will need to `UPDATE` them first, *before* performing the `ALTER`.

Then, personally, I would recommend creating a named constraint, like so:

```sql
ALTER TABLE dbo.ImagingEvents ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Site_SiteId DEFAULT 1 FOR Site_SiteId;
```

Having named constraints, rather than the automatically named ones, is far better for transferable code.